# Scale all layout elevemts to fit landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, landscape-portrait

I have an activity layout defined as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/tv_example"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="@string/tv_example"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:maxHeight="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_item_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:text="@string/button_edit"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which produces the following on portrait mode:

[[image: portrait mode[1]]

But, when switching it to landscape mode, the button disappears:

[image: landscape mode]

How can I make the missing `TextView` appear at landscape mode,
Or better yet - scale all items to fit the new orientation?

Basically, The text views are the important views - I want them to be visible, even at the cost of downsizing the `Button` and\or the `ImageView`

I've tried removing the `android:layout_weight="1"` line from the most-inner `LinearLayout` containing the `TextView` -

This makes the text apear in landscape mode, But makes the `Button` dissappear:

(It also makes the entire layout to be aligned to the top instead of the center of the screen in portrait mode)

[image: no weight landscape]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice in such situation is to have **2 layout files**, one for each orientation.

Create a new folder under your /res directory and call it layout-land in Android Studio and put your layout xml files for the landscape with the same naming.

Upon orientation change Android OS will use the xml file from that folder instead of trying to adjust the original one. This is the recommended approach for orientation support.

Comment: Followed your advice to handle lanscape mode view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have mentioned **android:layout_margin="50dp"** for your **Button** which is affecting your layout rendering to push the elements up.
This is resulting in hiding the textview. Try modifying the layout with less margin or using padding as an alternative. This might be helpful to retain all the elements in the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

@Adiel - Create a new folder under your /res directory and call it layout-land in Android Studio and put your layout xml files for the landscape with the same naming.

Totally agree with this as Android Studio gives you an option to create a separate one upon request. Ensure any layout_width and layout_heights are defined as match_parent doesn't seem to work.